# Magento Redirects To Homepage When Not Adding HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, magento1.9.3

Recently we made a change to our domain to force WWW and HTTPS. However, I notice now if I type a url without the https it redirects to homepage. Is this something that can be fixed in .htaccess?

Try this: therapydogvest.com/service-dog-vests.html
It should be going to this page https://www.therapydogvest.com/service-dog-vests.html

We are on Magento 1.9.3.2

Comment: Can you post your redirect code?

Answer (score 0):

For nginx you can use

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

`$request_uri` will pass the url to the redirect

for apache / .htacces you can use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

$1 here is the same as nginx , it will pass on the url on redirect.

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work.  I tried                                             RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.therapydogvest.com/$1 [L,R=301][/code]